# VBA - using Substitute and Proper functions combined

Tags: vba, excel

I can use this on the sheet level...

```
=SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"'", "qx")), "qx", "'")
```

And I can use this on the module level..

```
ActiveCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(ActiveCell.Value)
```

But I can't seem to get *this* to work on the module level...

```
ActiveCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Proper(Substitute(ActiveCell.Value, "'", "qx")), "qx", "'")
```

I receive a "Sub or Function not defined" error.

I've been struggling with this for so long that I've lost track of all of the different variants I've tried. 
I could really use some fresh eyes and some function-nesting know-how. This is driving me crazy.

(btw, this is meant to alter the existing cell value into Proper case, as well as to fix the quirk of the Proper function from capitalizing any letter that follows an apostrophe)

Comment: `Proper` and `Substitute` are also worksheet functions...  You can use the VBA `Replace()` in place of `Substitute()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reference the Application.WorksheetFunction object with each call to one as it doesnt know obout the methods otherwise.

```
ActiveCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(ActiveCell.Value, "'", "qx")), "qx", "'")
```

Comment: and thats 'about' above...i am not Canadian!

Comment: Thank you Sorceri. That was very instructive! It never occurred to me that it would be necesary to apply the WorksheetFunction to inside nested functions, but it perfectly explains the type of error that I was receiving. Many thanks for the valuable lesson.